# Excel - One Slicer To Rule Them All

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2013

In excel I have multiple sheets with different pivot tables and charts. Each of the sheets has different slicers, but they all share one in common. I would like to make a global slicer on my main sheet where, if I change this slicer, all of the other slicers change accordingly.

I have been successful by right clicking on the slicer and modifying the "Report Connections", but this ties all of the slicers together in both directions. So if I go to one of my sheets and only want to change that sheet specific slicer, then it still changes all the other slicers.

Does anyone know how I can make a global slicer to update all of the slicers at once, but still be able to change the slicers on each page separately from each other? Thanks!

Comment: I think your best bet would be to create a macro that enables connections, changes the slicer, and then disables connections. This macro can be tied to an event in the slicer, or it can be tied to a data validation button or drop-down list

Comment: That would be a good idea, the only problem is that once you create the connections, they are all tied to eachother so I can't disable the connections and reenable them to their own separate tables because any connection change I make from that point forward is applied to all the connections.

Comment: seems tricky.. someone here probably has an idea though